# I don't know the correct name of what I'm looking for!

Tags: word-choice

I'm not sure what the thing that I'm searching for is called when you'd rather use a different word choice than the word you're using instead, but has the same meaning though. Where would I find a list of different word choices to use that has the same meaning?

Comment: You are looking for [synonyms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synonym) which are listed in a [thesaurus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thesaurus).

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for a [thesaurus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thesaurus)

Comment: Or a reverse dictionary